# Change Jquery object value

Tags: jquery, object, count, addition

I've got a question about using Jquery objects.

This is my code, it's a drag and drop system but i removed the code for readability. If something is dropped i want to ++ the number in the jquery object. If banana is dropped the object must be "banana" : 2. And i want to 'echo' that out.

Hopefully you guys can help me!

```
var count_food = {
   "apple" : 1,
   "banana" : 1,
   "kiwi" : 1
}

var food = $('.food').attr('data-food');

if ( $('.score').children().hasClass(food) ){

   count_food.food++;
   $('.score').append("<div class='" + food + "'><span class='count'> + count_food.food + </span></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
count_food[food] =count_food[food] +1;
```

Comment: A bit late with my comment, but with a little bit of tweaking this fixed my problem!